# How do I fix a deprecated module for plotly.plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am just beginning my Python journey and trying to replicate code from:
[Using Python and Auto ARIMA to Forecast Seasonal Time Series](https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/using-python-and-auto-arima-to-forecast-seasonal-time-series-90877adff03c)

When I attempt to run the following:

```
import plotly.plotly as ply
```

I receive the following import error:

> The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
> please install the chart-studio package and use the
> chart_studio.plotly module instead.

I have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling plotly into my Anaconda instance, but to no avail.

Answer (score 17):

The following steps serve the purpose:

1. Installing `chart-studio` by running the following in Anaconda Prompt:

```
pip install chart-studio
```

2. Importing plotly from `chart-studio` package by running:

```
from chart_studio import plotly
```

in place of `from plotly import plotly`.

One can learn more about `chart-studio` [here](https://pypi.org/project/chart-studio/).

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, you can use `plotly` as follows:

```
from chart_studio import plotly
```

After that, you can use other associated libraries as usual:

```
import plotly.offline as pyoff
import plotly.graph_objs as go
```

I hope this was useful

Answer (score 4):

Downgrading the version helps. Try this:

```
!pip install plotly==3.10.0
from chart_studio import plotly
```

This solved my error in google colab

Answer (score 1):

Install `chart-studio` with `pip install chart-studio` at the command line/terminal.

Answer (score 1):

First, install the chart-studio conda package.

```
conda install -c plotly chart-studio
```

Then use the following to import pyplot instead of "import plotly.plotly as ply"

```
from chart-studio import pyplot as ply
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
import plotly.offline as pyoff
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig=dict(data=go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3,4],y=[1,4,9,16],mode = "lines+markers"))
pyoff.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).